# Load images without scale

Tags: fabricjs

I'm looking for a solution to load images without any scale, with custom width and height.

```
 fabric.util.loadImage('path', (imgElement) => {
  let instance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
    top: this.canvas.getHeight() - height,
    left: (this.canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (width / 2),
    width: width,
    height: height
  });

  this.canvas.add(instance);
  this.canvas.renderAll();
});
```

I want my image to have dimensions 'width' and 'height'. The object drawn has the right dimensions but the image is not fully displayed.

The result:
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtlSJ.png)

The original image:
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JINJ6.png)

Thank's for your help,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution using scaleX and scaleY parameters.
Unable to use scaleToWidth() or scaleToHeight() for this case.

```
    fabric.util.loadImage('path', (imgElement) => {
      let instance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
        top: this.canvas.getHeight() - height,
        left: (this.canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (width / 2),
      });

      instance.set({scaleX: width / instance.width, scaleY: height / instance.height});
      instance.setCoords();

      this.canvas.add(instance);
      this.canvas.renderAll();
    });
```